# What's a good way to maintain organization with multiple platform/IDE projects?

Tags: ide, cross-platform, organization

I am working on a few games that work on both Windows and Mac and am using Visual Studio 2010 and Xcode 4.3.

To devs that are using multiple IDEs, what does your organization look like in terms of main project files, resource files (sounds, texture, setting) and platform specific files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most developers use the same IDE and version (e.g. VS2010), but for others and those using different tools it's their responsibility to maintain their own project files (well, VS2008 and VS2010 can share *.csproj files, but they have different *.sln files so it isn't a huge problem).

Projects are laid out in the usual way: Solution files in the root (named according to the IDE, e.g. "Foobar-VS2008.sln" and "Foobar-VS2010.sln") and then each project exists under the root and in the root of each project are the *.csproj files which are shared between IDEs.

However I have worked in more complicated projects, especially large and popular open-source projects where people like to hack C in vim as well as VC. In those cases the project and solution files actually exist in their own directory off the root, and as before, each IDE's developers are responsible for maintaining their project files. The structure looks like this:

```
PopularProject        (Empty)
PopularProject\src    (Root for all the *.c and *.h goodness)
PopularProject\bin    (Where the myriad build systems dump their output in a suitable subdirectory (e.g. \bin\VC9\IA-64 or \bin\gcc\x86)
PopularProject\prj\VC9 (Where VC9 project and SLN files go)
PopularProject\prj\gcc (Where GCC makefiles and other files go)
PopularProject\prj\Eclipse (Ditto, but for Eclipse)
```

It keeps projects organised, but it only really works for large projects. For small ones it's overkill and often it's easier just having a single project and *.sln file and if someone wants to add their own then they can do that, but only on their own machine (i.e. don't let minorities add their own files, not to be discriminatory, but to keep things simple and easy to manage).

For projects that use platform-specific code then there's a liberal application of #if WIN32 or #if LINUX pre-processor defines in the source.

All third-party or imported libraries tend to go in a "lib" or "ref" subdirectory off the project root.

I haven't worked on a game directly, but assets are stored off root in another tree of the filesystem. Developers don't want them being included when doing a diff between their local machine and source-control (also binaries are a bitch to diff). They are the responsibility of artists who are (supposed to be) a different team, after all.